# Account Suspended - Possible to increase time between the Mails sent?

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, timer, gmail, mailmerge

My Google Workspace Account was recently Disabled/ Suspended as it seems like I violated the Workspace Policy by sending too many emails regularly using the Mail Merge.

I work for a small start-up and we use all possible free tools for Lead Generation and Prospecting. So I was using Mail Merge to reach out to a bunch of leads in one go.

Is there a way to set a timer or set limits between one email and the next so that Google doesn't think I am spamming?

Ideally, I would want to plug in a code somewhere in the script that would help me to "slow" the process down by sending a mail every 1-2 minutes, unlike what it currently does, which is sending it as soon as the last one is done - within a second.

I would be really grateful if someone could help me with the piece of code and also tell me where to insert the same. Thank you in advance !!

Side Note - I seem to be hitting the limit at 750 mails per day and not 1500 as listed in the Documentation

Comment: How about [Utilities.sleep()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep(Integer))?

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for your response. Where would I plug this in the code?

Comment: Where do you wish to add the delay?

Comment: I want the delay to be after each mail sent

Comment: Well then put it right after the sendMail()

Comment: Thank you very much ! This works. Now I am able to send a mail every 1.5 minutes.

I hope this helps my account not get suspended again !